# Replacing part of of an attribute value using cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, cheerio

I need to replace the sub string `target` with the string `deploy` for the `href` value of the following element using gulp-cheerio:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../target/test/css/index.css">
```

Comment: I haven't used cheerio before, but assuming the jQuery syntax will work, you do `$('link[href="href="../../../target/test/css/index.css"]').attr('href', $('link[href="href="../../../target/test/css/index.css"]').attr('href').replace('target', 'deploy'))` The href for the link looks messed up, just copy any pasted, but I think having the href equal an href is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used cheerio before, but assuming the jQuery syntax will work, you do

```
.pipe(cheerio(function($, file) {
  $('link[href="../../../target/test/css/index.css"]').attr('href',
    $('link[href="../../../target/test/css/index.css"]').attr('href').replace('target', 'deploy'));
}))
```